# ActiveRecord find Option with :conditions : how to replace backslash \ with double backslash \\ if :conditions is a string instead of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, conditional-statements, backslash

I have the problem that rails 2.X  do not replaces a backslash (\) with two backslashes (\\) , if  :conditions is a string. It only replaces it with two backslashes, when you have a hash for  :conditions e.g. following:

```
Parameter.find(:first, :conditions =>{ :key1 => var.to_s })
```

But in my case :conditions is not a  hash, but a string. How it can replaces the "\" automatically in a correct way with "\\", if I do not want to use gsub-function?

My Problem is, that my  :conditions is a very long string, which contains a backslash. And because of different reasons ( include option , ...).  I cannot use a hash for it. The following find-thing do not replaces "\" automatically with "\\" .

```
var =  "test\test"

Parameter.find(:first, :conditions => ' key1 = \'' + var.to_s + '\''  )
```

I would be thankful for any helpful hint, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array conditions:

```
Parameter.first :conditions => ["key1 = ?", var]
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions for more info.

Comment: If you are using Rails 3+, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions is the right link.

Comment: @Vijay: thanks, I'm still stuck on 2.3 at work so I didn't notice that I linked to the older docs.

Comment: And if I use LIKE Operator, how I can force rails to make "\\\\" of "\\" ? Unfortunately the backslash must be escaped two times. Or is gsub the only way there?